# How to simulate a device with python

Tags: python, python-requests

Im developing a bot for a game, and its only allowed 3 accounts per ip/device.

Is there anyway to simulate a new device using python?

Ex:

```
import requests

device1 = requests.get('random ip', 'url', 'etc')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can google some free proxy and do the following:

```
import requests
import random

tests = 5

proxy = [
    {
        'http': 'http://[IP_ADDR]:[PORT]',
        'https': 'https://[IP_ADDR]:[PORT]',
    },
    {
        'http': 'http://[IP_ADDR]:[PORT]',
        'https': 'https://[IP_ADDR]:[PORT]',
    }
]
url = '[YOUR_TARGET]'

for i in range(tests)
    response = requests.get(url,proxies=random.choice(proxy))
```